# add watermark or logo to mediaelement.js player

Tags: mediaelement.js

I like to add a logo/watermarkt to my mediaelement.js player (top left) but haven't had much luck. Anyone got any tips/ideas how to implement this for mediaelement.js?

Answer (score 1):

You can absolutely position an element or image over the player. I've had good results doing this with alternate images for the mejs-overlay-button. You'll want to make sure that you have the z-index on the logo set so that it appears over all the player layers. You'll also want to make sure the transparency on the image works well over video.